# Lookup on small substring (in a big string value) exists in array

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula where my cell has a big string. I need to search whether a substring of this value matches with an array

E.G:
Say I have a long String
**"Life is Beautiful"**

I have a set of Arrays like below

```
||SubString  || Description ||
||Beautiful  || 1 ||
||Optimistic || 2 ||
```

So I should have a formula where it should return me the Description. In this case **1**. How can I achieve this? I tried to use VLookup, If Else but it doesn't give me the solution what I am expecting.

Comment: Will there always be no more than one match? E.g. is a string like "Life is Beautiful and Optimistic" a possibility?

Comment: Let us consider there will not be more than one match but there will be a possibility to have no match atall

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "InStr" function, if using VBA. See below:

```
Sub Cells_Test()

Dim check As Integer

check = InStr(Cells(1, 1).Value, "Beautiful")

If check >= 1 Then Cells(1, 3).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value

End Sub
```

This returns the value "1" (Cell B1) if Cell A1 contained the string "beautiful".

You can also control what happens if there is no match by doing:

```
If check = 0 Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question 100%, but you might be looking for something like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$3,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$3,E2)),ROW($A$1:$A$2)))
```

[image]

Wrap in `IFERROR` to handle the possibility of no match. Note that it will also fail if there is more than one match.